# Compare between 2 tables and insert missing records pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

We have a pl sql procedure in which we get xml data with multiple records, first gets stored in temp table, by verifying or after doing some checks on the received xml in a loop we are inserting into another table which is the final table, some times few records are not getting pushed to final table for some reason,
now in the same plsql code at the end of loop, we need to recheck is all the rows from the temp table say table A got inserted into the other table say B.
Ex:
Employee Records with columns in table A

```
<Employee>
Empid, empname, empdesg, empaddr,empemail, empMobNo
</Employee>
```

Employee Records with columns in table B

```
<Employee>
EmpNo, empFirstName, EmpLevel, empAddress, empContactDetails, empPhNum
</Employee>
```

Now we have got 30 employee records from source to plsql which got stored in Table A, but for some reasons only 27 got inserted into Table B, need to compare for missing records in Table B and re insert them into Table B from table A based on empid/empNo.

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: I think You can use MINUS operator here.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an to review [ask]. Your description makes it seem like some rows in your temp table are failing the checks and therefore not getting written to the permanent table. This seems like perfectly normal *and expected* processing. But now you want to push those failed rows any way. If that is the case then why waist time doing the checks?

Answer (score 0):

Thi is the idea:

```
   INSERT INTO B
    SELECT * FROM A WHERE empid IN
    (
    SELECT empid FROM A
    MINUS
    SELECT empNo FROM B
    );
```